# Differentiation under the integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Now I have this expression.

$\psi(\theta)=\text{log}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{\{\Delta\theta-f(\nu)\Delta^2\}}h(\Delta)d\Delta$. The expression of  $h(.)$ is not given. So $h(\Delta)$ is some function of $\Delta$ which is not given. What is $\psi'(\theta)$?.

Comment: Interesting choice of the name of the integrating variable. I had to read it several times, but that is probably just me not being used to $\Delta$ as a variable. Is it common in some branch of mathematics, or is it just your choice of variable?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiation with respect to $\theta$ will give
$$
\psi'(\theta)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Delta\exp{\{\Delta\theta-f(\nu)\Delta^2\}}h(\Delta)\ \mathrm{d} \Delta}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{\{\Delta\theta-f(\nu)\Delta^2\}}h(\Delta) \ \mathrm{d}\Delta}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but was hoping for a much simplified version.  Integration by parts seems to fail.